# How to represent aggregates in a data warehouse

Tags: data-warehouse, aggregate

I am building the dimensional model for a data warehouse (as an exercise for a mini-course I am doing) and I want to build an aggregate to speed up queries.

Basically, I want the aggregate to group by:

```
(PizzaType), (Size), (Month), (Year)
```

I would have `num_pizza_types * num_sizes * num_months * num_years aggregate` rows.  One row for all combinations of that.  But how does this change my dimensional model (or aggregate schema, I suppose)?  How is this represented in the dimensional model?  Do I remove all columns except month/year from my Date dimension?  Do I remove all columns except Size and PizzaType from my Pizza dimension?

Answer (score 1):

You should not change your date or pizza dimensions. What you need is a fact table that keeps your aggregate data.

Therefore you will have Date dimension with these columns:

DateId -Pk

Day

Month

Quarter

Year

DateName

....

Your Pizza dimension will be like:
PizzaId -Pk

PizzaName

PizzaSize

PizzaType

...

And now your fact table which will be linked to the dimensions above using their IDs:

Create Table PizzaSale (keeps the aggregate data):
Id

PizzaId -Fk to Pizza dimension

SaleMonthId -Fk to Date dimension

Pizza_total_sale -Aggregate value

... Other aggregate values if needed

So as you can see by joining these 3 tables you can get the number of sold pizzas per month. The type can be got from Pizza dimension.